Nanodrop is suggesting that a PCR reaction worked but no bands show up when I run the PCR products on an agarose gel
I ran a PCR to extract and amplify a gene I need from a plasmid.
The nanodrop measurements show an increase in the amount of DNA present after the PCR reaction, and the A260/280 is ~1.8, so I think it is measuring DNA and not contaminant.
When I run the product on a gel however, there is no band present, not even any non-specific bands.
I have tried increasing the percentage of the gel to make sure the DNA isn't running off, and increasing the amount of DNA I load onto the gel. Neither worked and there is still no band.
Does this suggest that the PCR didn't work and that I should re-try the PCR? Or should I try to re-run the gel and change something else?


did you run a positive control using the same DNA template and reagents other than the primers? 2) what happens if you take the amplicon sample and re-PCR it? (Danger: you will want to confirm that the product is right by some means if you do this) 3) what happens if you run the reaction in a RTPCR machine and watch the curve? 4) what is your PCR protocol?


Trust your gel and trust your controls.
The Nano-drop can't tell you whether you have a PCR product or not. ND measures UV-vis absorption of organic compounds with coordinated double bonds in your sample, not whole single-stranded or double-stranded DNA. It only gives you a DNA concentration because you're telling it your sample contains DNA rather than some other absorptive substance. A nucleotide has about the same absorption spectrum whether it's incorporated into a PCR product, a primer, or just free floating dNTPs. You added a bunch of primers and dNTPs to your PCR reaction, and that's why you have a higher concentration on the Nano-drop. The nanodrop concentration in the reaction mix shouldn't really change based on whether it worked or not.
